# Powershell WMI: Runs without any errors/exceptions, however doesn't execute script

Tags: powershell, usb, wmi

```
$filter = ([wmiclass]"\\.\root\subscription:__EventFilter").CreateInstance()

$filter.QueryLanguage = "WQL"
$filter.Query = "Select * from __InstanceCreationEvent within 5 where targetinstance isa 'win32_logicaldisk'"
$filter.Name = "USBFilter"
$filter.EventNamespace = 'root\cimv2'

$result = $filter.Put()
$filterPath = $result.Path

$consumer = ([wmiclass]"\\.\root\subscription:CommandLineEventConsumer").CreateInstance()
$consumer.Name = 'USBConsumer'
$consumer.CommandLineTemplate = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe –ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file C:\test.ps1"
$consumer.ExecutablePath = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
$consumer.WorkingDirectory = "C:\"
$result = $consumer.Put()
$consumerPath = $result.Path

$bind = ([wmiclass]"\\.\root\subscription:__FilterToConsumerBinding").CreateInstance()

$bind.Filter = $filterPath
$bind.Consumer = $consumerPath
$result = $bind.Put()
$bindPath = $result.Path
```

The above code is supposed to run a script when windows detects a USB device is inserted it runs fine (no error/warnings/exceptions) however on the insertion of a device, the script, which is supposed to display a message box. Doesn't. I have tested the triggered script on its own and the dialogue box displays fine.

I am really not all that familiar with WMIs and persistant one even less, so any help at all would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the event consumer will be invoked by a WMI host process running under the `SYSTEM` account, you won't see anything in your own desktop session.

If you change your `C:\test.ps1` contents to write to the event log instead:

```
$LogSource = "USB Detector"

if(-not [System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists($LogSource))
{
    New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source $LogSource
}
Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source $LogSource -EventId 100 -Message "New disk attached!"
```

You'll see that it works fine:

[image]